# How to copy list elements in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Regarding the code below:

```py
A = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
A[0] = A[1]
B = A[:][0]
B[0] = 5
print(A)
print(B)
```

I'm wondering why printing `B` gives `[5, 4]`.

I thought that `B = A[:][0]` is the same as `A[0][0]`, `A[1][0]`, which would then be `[3, 3]`. Then, `B[0] = 5`, so it would print `[5, 3]`.

Could someone kindly clear up my confusion?

Comment: [How do I clone a list so that it doesn't change unexpectedly after assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-do-i-clone-a-list-so-that-it-doesnt-change-unexpectedly-after-assignment)

Answer (score 2):

after this line:

```
A[0] = A[1]
```

A = [[3,4],[3,4]]

`A[:]`
will return A itself, so when you access 0, you will get [3,4]

```
B = A[:][0]
```

and after putting 5,    B = [5,4]

Answer (score 1):

Using the `copy()` method is relatively straightforward.

```py
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
b = a.copy()

print(a)
print(b)
```

result

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

If you want to make copies of the nested lists, then you would extend to this:

```py
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
b = [a[0].copy(), a[1].copy()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your confusion:

> I thought that B = A[:][0] is the same as A[0][0], A[1][0]

It's not. The `:` symbol in Python isn't used for that sort of shorthand like in some other languages. `A[:]` simply returns a copy of `A`, so `A[:][0]` is equivalent to `A[0]`, which in this context is `[3, 4]`.

(The more general use of the `:` is for an operation called *slicing*, which is when you copy only part of a list, from a given starting index to a given end index. If we omit the indices, they default to the start and end of the entire list, so we copy the whole thing.)